# Remove object from JSON array

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have an JSON array who looks like this:

```
[ {
  "name" : "1",
  "date" : "30/03 19:36:20"
}, {
  "name" : "12",
  "date" : "30/03 19:36:21"
}, {
  "name" : "123",
  "date" : "30/03 19:36:22"
}, {
  "name" : "1234",
  "date" : "30/03 19:36:23"
}, {
  "name" : "12345",
  "date" : "30/03 19:36:25"
} ]
```

How could I possibly delete one object by its name in java, like let's suppose I wanna delete the 1

```
 {
  "name" : "1",
  "date" : "30/03 19:36:20"
},
```

How could I possibly delete just those lines, because my code at the moment deletes all entries from the file

```
public static void deleteSavefile() throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(new File("savefiles.json"));
    for (JsonNode node : jsonNode) {
        ((ObjectNode)node).remove("name");
        ((ObjectNode)node).remove("date");
    }
    objectMapper.writeValue(new File("savefiles.json"), jsonNode);
}
```

Comment: What progress have you made till now? What approach are you following to parse and operate on this json?

Comment: I have a code but It removes all entries, not just one

Comment: @TerchilăMarian Which library are you using?

Comment: I'm using jackson

Comment: post the code here @TerchilăMarian

Comment: @TerchilăMarian check out the Stream version in my answer, if you prefer immutability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `jsonNode` is an `Array` of `Objects` then `jsonNode.elements()` returns Iterator<`JsonNode>`, by using `if` condition check the node with `name equals 1` then delete the entire node

```
 JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(new File("savefiles.json"));
Iterator<JsonNode> nodes = jsonNode.elements()
 while(nodes.hasNext()) {
     if(nodes.next().get("name").textValue().equals("1")){
           nodes.remove();
           }
       }
```

Comment: Your code works except that it doesn't delete the brackets at the end of execution, [{},{"name":"12","date":"30/03 19:36:21"},{"name":"123","date":"30/03 19:36:22"},{"name":"1234","date":"30/03 19:36:23"},{"name":"12345","date":"30/03 19:36:25"}]

Comment: I've tried but still cannot  get rid of the empty brackets

Comment: check the updated code @TerchilăMarian that should work

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove an element from the `ArrayNode`, just

```
final JsonNode json = objectMapper.readTree(new File("savefiles.json"));

if (json.isArray()) {
    for (final Iterator<JsonNode> i = json.elements(); i.hasNext(); ) {
        final JsonNode jsonNode = i.next();

        if ("1".equals(jsonNode.get("name").asText())) {
            i.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

This will **not** create a new instance. The original `TreeNode` (which is an `ArrayNode`) is maintained.
Note also the `.asText()` while comparing.

A Stream version is

```
final ArrayNode filtered =
        StreamSupport.stream(json.spliterator(), false)
                     .filter(e -> !"1".equals(e.get("name").asText()))
                     .collect(Collector.of(
                             objectMapper::createArrayNode,
                             (array, element) -> array.add(element),
                             (result, toMerge) -> result.addAll(result)
                     ));
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the json in the list, iterate on the list, find the element and remove it.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
// read in a list
List<Map<String, String>> jsonList = objectMapper.readValue(new File("savefiles.json"), new TypeReference<List<Map<String, String>>>(){});

// remove object with name "1"
jsonList = jsonList.stream().filter(e -> !"1".equals(e.get("name"))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can simplify more by defining a bean class with two field `name` and `date` then instead of `List<Map<String, String>` you can use `List<BeanClass>`.

```
// read in a list
List<BeanClass> jsonList = objectMapper.readValue(new File("savefiles.json"), new TypeReference<List<BeanClass>>(){});

// remove object with name "1"
jsonList = jsonList.stream().filter(e -> !"1".equals(e.getName())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Wrote code directly here, there might be some typo.